# skype web integration

Tags: javascript, skype

I m trying to integrate Skype video call and chatting option in my php website. i went to developer option in Skype there i created a button and integrate that to my website. Chatting and attachment sending to ok but when i m trying to call or video call i m getting a error. Error code bellow:

My code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> </title>
</head>
<body>
<span class="skype-button bubble " data-contact-id="xyz"></span>
<script src="https://swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/v1/sdk.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

error code :
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<Error>
<Code>BlobNotFound</Code>
<Message>
The specified blob does not exist. RequestId:dd809c22-f01e-010c-77ce-f04c40000000 Time:2018-05-21T06:41:37.5066812Z
</Message>
</Error>
```

Comment: The question is not related to php at all.

Comment: Doesn't sound promising, this question is asked a lot on Microsoft's forums but no answer is ever given directly https://www.google.com.au/search?q=skype+The+specified+blob+does+not+exist.+RequestId+site:answers.microsoft.com&rlz=1C1GCEA_enAU784AU784&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTpMrUopbbAhUJTY8KHWr0CcgQrQIIMigEMAA&biw=1518&bih=738&safe=active&ssui=on your BotID is correct as outlined here isn't it? https://dev.skype.com/webcontrol